# Create draft mail using Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I want to know if it's possible to create draft mail using Google Apps script.
And if yes, how is it possible ?

Regards,
Sebastien

Comment: It appears that there's a new way to do this at the end of that [Issue 985 page](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=985), using the new Gmail API announced recently. Finally!

Comment: Updated [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17661714/1677912) with details from @alan's comment.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the draft in the gmail web interface after creation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google added support for generating drafts in September 2017. From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createDraft(String,String,String)):

```
// The code below creates a draft email with the current date and time.
var now = new Date();
GmailApp.createDraft("mike@example.com", "current time", "The time is: " + now.toString());
```

Answer (score 17):

At this point in time, there is no way to create a new message that appears in your `Drafts` folder. This functionality has been requested previously - see [Issue 985](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=985). If you are interested in receiving any updates, visit and star the issue.

**EDIT:** While still not natively supported in Google Apps Script, you can create drafts by using the GMail API, using `getOAuthToken()` to authenticate (introduced Feb 2014). Drafts support was added to the API in June 2014, and an example of its use from GAS is shown in [comment 29](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=985#c29) of the above issue. Code reproduced here for convenience:

```
function createDraft() {

  var forScope = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount(); // needed for auth scope

  var raw = 
      'Subject: testing Draft\n' + 
      //'To: test@test.com\n' +
      'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=1234567890123456789012345678\n' +
      'testing Draft msg\n' + 
      '--1234567890123456789012345678--\n';

  var draftBody = Utilities.base64Encode(raw);

  var params = {method:"post",
                contentType: "application/json",
                headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
                muteHttpExceptions:true,
                payload:JSON.stringify({
                  "message": {
                    "raw": draftBody
                  }
                })
               };

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts", params);
  Logger.log(resp.getContentText());
  /*
   * sample resp: {
   *   "id": "r3322255254535847929",
   *   "message": {
   *     "id": "146d6ec68eb36de8",
   *     "threadId": "146d6ec68eb36de8",
   *     "labelIds": [ "DRAFT" ]
   *   }
   * }
   */
}
```

Comment: +1 for follow-up ;) always good to know you keep an eye on all this !

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible to do so. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app).

Answer (score 1):

I do this via Zapier now - it's fantastic.

See this zap http://zpr.io/fhmT

Google's documentation on the subject is here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/drafts