# Google Apps Script - create draft Gmail email message WITH embedded graphics

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail-api

I want to create a draft Gmail email message using Google Apps Script, like in the following example taken from Mogsdad's accepted answer to the [Create draft mail using Google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660601/create-draft-mail-using-google-apps-script) question:

```
function createDraft() {

  var forScope = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount(); // needed for auth scope

  var raw = 
      'Subject: testing Draft\n' + 
      //'To: test@test.com\n' +
      'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=1234567890123456789012345678\n' +
      'testing Draft msg\n' + 
      '--1234567890123456789012345678--\n';

  var draftBody = Utilities.base64Encode(raw);

  var params = {method:"post",
                contentType: "application/json",
                headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
                muteHttpExceptions:true,
                payload:JSON.stringify({
                  "message": {
                    "raw": draftBody
                  }
                })
               };

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts", params);

  Logger.log(resp.getContentText());
```

It works great, BUT I want to embedd some image in the message body, without linking to external URL, so it always shows up, it's not blocked by some email clients, including Gmail. How to do that?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to embed an image in the message body. Actually even in the Gmail API there is no way that we can insert the image through code in the message.

Comment: I thought there could be a method like encoding bitmaps into HTML code. Pity :(