# Pulling data from Sheets into Gmail template - one email at a time, not a bulk mail merge

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm trying to come up with a solution that will allow me to (1) pull data from Sheets for only ONE of the rows into a Gmail template and (2) allow for modifying the template with additional information that's not in the spreadsheet before sending it off.

Context: My organization uses an intake/referral log to track key information about referrals. Once info is in the Sheet, they manually send an email assigning the referral to an employee for follow-up. Much of the info in the Sheet is retyped...which initially made me think of automating this fully with AppsScript, so that all the standard info (case #, case type, due dates, etc) is included in that email. However, the emails sometimes have a paragraph or three of contextual information that we don't want to store in the spreadsheets and have pulled into the automated email.

So my goal is to pull the data from the spreadsheet into the email where I can (vs having to retype it) AND allow the addition of contextual info before sending it off to the assigned employee.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this? I haven't found a mail merge add-on or Apps Script solution that allows doing this one row at a time and adding in extra custom info into the email.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the kind of question that  each designer has to come to grips with everytime they design a new solution.  And each answer is often unique to the designer.  In the end you will have to make these decisions based upon your current knowledge and the needs of your organization.  My opinion is that you will find it valuable to work closely with a consultant that knows the programming inorder to arrive at a soluton that works well with your current work flow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660601/create-draft-mail-using-google-apps-script

Comment: @a-burge  - Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - I was able to work with createDraft(recipient, subject, body, options) and get what I needed. Link for those wanting more info here:  [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#createDraft(String,String,String))  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

So this question, as currently written, could clearly be accomplished a whole bunch of different ways. With that in mind, here is one quick and dirty way in which it **might** be accomplished:

1. On the spreadsheet where the data is stored, create a script via tools>script editor.
2. Using that script, [create a menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu) which runs a function that does the following, perhaps in an endless loop:

   a. [Prompt the user](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response) for the email address of where to send the email if it isn't in the spreadsheet or a token value, such as an empty string, to end the script.

   b. [Prompt the user](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response) for the number of the row where the info is stored.

   c. [Prompt the user](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/prompt-response) for any extra contextual information to add to the email.

   d. Get the info from the applicable row in the spreadsheet.

   e. Create a nicely formatted email and send it off.

From there, the person in charge of doing the referrals would simply run the script and feed it the required information. Clearly human error could fowl things up here, but without more details of exactly how you want this to work, it isn't really possible to define exactly how to best protect against human error. Reading up on [Data Validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation) might give you a start on that front.

And if you are still completely lost, I happen to be a Google Apps Script tutor/consultant who often gives away free tutoring/consulting. See [tutoringbyroger.com](http://www.tutoringbyroger.com) for more on that.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and proposed solution design. I've worked with custom menus before and a little bit on prompts...but the links you provided will help deepen my knowledge. Thanks!